# Difference between AWS IoT Device SDKs and AWS IoT Device Client

Tags: aws-iot

I am learning the way to use AWS and searching to understand the Difference between AWS IoT Device SDKs and AWS IoT Device Client.
Finally, I want to use Raspberry Pi for Telemetry, but which set of tools should I use AWS IoT Device SDKs OR AWS IoT Device Client.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with Raspberry Pi, I would recommend you to use AWS IOT Device sdk. Specifically AWS IOT Device SDK for Python or Nodejs. Further using AWS IOT Device SDK :

1. Register Thing in AWS IOT Console
2. Register Certificates and Download them
3. Copy over Certificates to Raspberry PI
4. Use Sample Application provided in AWS IOT SDK GitHub and connect to AWS IOT and start publishing messages.

Here is the helpful repo to get you started : https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python

Answer (score 1):

AWS IoT Device Client looks like a complete software running on Linux (according to AWS description). AWS IoT Device SDKs on the other hand are libraries that allows you to connect your devices to AWS-IOT through mqtt and websockets protocol.

I personally would go with the classic SDKs approach for the reason that not enough information other than AWS Docs are available for Device Client so far

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IoT Device client to embed within the Firmware of a Device however AWS IOT SDK is more of a library for accessing AWS resources programmatically.

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer as is. Please elaborate more on your answer by providing examples and/or documentations.